# Possible to fork a process outside from it?

Tags: unix, fork

Well, it is obvious, let's say we have two processes `A` and `F`. `F` wants to fork `A` when it has the CPU control (and `A` is suspended since CPU is on `F`).

I have Googled however nothing related showed up. Is such a thing possible in Unix environments?

Comment: Can you explain better your goal ? Why are you putting a process F in the picture while it seems all you want is cloning process A from the outside. Assuming only one process can have the CPU control at a time is getting quite obsolete these days.

Comment: I was just curious. Can't we fork a process from outside that program code? There's no further goal.

Comment: Curious you accept an answer telling it's impossible while I and later Askurtun with technical details both answered it's possible ...

Comment: You're right. I actually didn't much think about it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea in any way, but it may be possible for process `F` to attach to `A` using a debugger interface such as `ptrace`. Doing something like suspending the target process, saving its state, diverting the process to run `fork`, then restoring its original state.

It should be noted that your cloning process will probably need to handle some odd cases around threads and the like.

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely no standard and/or portable way to clone a process from the outside but depending on the OS, there are certainly possible ways to divert a process from its task and force it to clone itself or do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible.

The [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) system call makes a copy of the parent, so if you call `fork()` in the `F` process, the child will be a copy of `F`, there's nothing you can do to change this behavior.

Comment: Maybe some `root` level process can read memory mappings of `A` and then create exact same code/stack/memory area with `process_t`. Can't people implement such a thing? Is there a limitation?

Comment: @Ahmet as far as I know, this isn't possible for security reasons, but I'm not a specialist at all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not possible is because, normally with `fork()`, there is exactly one difference to start out with between the two processes: the return value of the fork() call itself. Without such a call inside the code of `A`, there is no way for the processes to have any difference between them, so they would both be doing exactly the same thing, when normally with you want one of the processes to start doing something different.

How exactly do you think what you want to do should work?

Answer (score 0):

No, this would be a huge security hole that would result in the leakage of sensitive information if it were possible.

At best, you could setup a signal handler in the parent process that would fork(2) off a child (maybe exec(2) a pre-configured child process?).

I think you would be better served by looking in to message passing between two processes that have CPU affinity setup, but even then, I think the gains would be nominal (over-optimizing a problem?).

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpuset&apropos=0&sektion=0

Comment: That is possible and that isn't a security hole providing the process belongs to you or you have administrative rights. Debuggers do that kind of tricks and worse all the time. Dtrace on Solaris or FreeBSD would also be a good candidate.

Comment: Correct. If UIDs match, you can do nearly anything to any other process. If the UIDs don't match, you aren't (and shouldn't) be allowed to do anything (unless you are root, at which point ... have fun).